# Extending Order Email template in Magento 2

Tags: sales-order, magento-2.1.3, order-email

I am trying to extend the **Order Confirmation Email Template** to add the custom attribute. When I am trying to add code to **core** class it's printing the value in the email template. When enabling to my extended module it's not printing the value.

For this, I have done code.

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" type="ABCSolutions\SalesEmail\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" />
</config>
```

**OrderSender.php**

```
/**
     * Prepare email template with variables
     *
     * @param Order $order
     * @return void
     */
    protected function prepareTemplate(Order $order)
    {

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface')->getById($order->getCustomerId());

        /** @param string $abccustomattribute*/
        $abccustomattribute = null;

        $customAttributes = $customer->getCustomAttributes();
        if(isset($customAttributes['abccustomattribute'])){
            $abccustomattributecode= $customAttributes['abccustomattribute'];
            if($abccustomattributecode->getAttributecode() == "abccustomattribute"){
                $abccustomattribute= $abccustomattributecode->getValue();
                $abccustomattribute.= " Working";
            }
        }

        file_put_contents('Order1.txt', print_r("\n" . 'API: ' . $abccustomattribute,true), FILE_APPEND);

        $transport = [
            'order' => $order,
            'billing' => $order->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $this->getPaymentHtml($order),
            'store' => $order->getStore(),
            'formattedShippingAddress' => $this->getFormattedShippingAddress($order),
            'formattedBillingAddress' => $this->getFormattedBillingAddress($order),
            'abccustomattribute' => $abccustomattribute
        ];

        $transport = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($transport);

        $this->eventManager->dispatch(
            'email_order_set_template_vars_before',
            ['sender' => $this, 'transport' => $transport]
        );

        $this->templateContainer->setTemplateVars($transport->getData());

        parent::prepareTemplate($order);
    }
```

After I have added the `{{var abccustomattribute}}` variable to **Order Email template** file `order_new.html` file.

Could you please suggest me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following code to add Custom data in the email template. 
**app/code/Anshu/Emails/registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Anshu_Emails',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Anshu/Emails/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Anshu_Emails" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Emails/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="anshu_emails_variable_order" instance="Anshu\Emails\Observer\AddMyData" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Emails/Observer/AddMyData.php**

```
<?php

namespace Anshu\Emails\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddMyData implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $transport = $observer->getTransport();
        $transport['myvar'] = 'My Value';
        if ($transport['payment_html'] == 'transfer') {
            $transport['payment_html'] = 'myvar';
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call a new data variable as `{{var myvar|raw}}` in the new order email template. You can create a new template from `Marketing -> Email Templates -> Add New Template`

Comment: Yes, I tried this yesterday not working. After I modified little thing it's working for me.

Comment: Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Hi, So how to override that `order_new.html` using module (not using theme)?

Comment: @fudu Why do you want to override the email template file? You can create email templates in admin.

Comment: @AnshuMishra Thanks, i've got it few hours ago, I've come to admin page and create new email template.

Comment: @Bojjaiah I have tried this thing, but didn't work for me. Can you please let me know which little modification you have done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DharaBhatti navigate to https://privnote.com/Rkq6jIhz#e7ydHCxFg